# No logro ver las imagenes al desplegar mi api node

Tags: javascript, nodejs, imagen, servidor

tengo el siguiente problema espero que puedan ayudarme.

tengo una Api desarrollada en Nodejs con express, la desplegue a un servidor ubuntu y todo va bien, excepto que no puedo ver las imagenes que cargo.

en la base de datos, se guarda la url correctamente, en la carapeta de storage dentro del servidor se guarda tambien correctamente, pero la url no funciona a la hora de ver la imagen.

Aclaración, esto en local funciona correcatamente, pero en el servidor remoto no me funciona.

```
import multer from "multer"

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './src/storage/imgs')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
      cb(null, uniqueSuffix + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
  })
  const upload = multer({ storage })
  
  module.exports = upload
```

este es el modulo de multer que uso para subir las imagenes.

```
ligaSchema.methods.setImgUrl = function setImgUrl (filename){
    const {host, port} = appConfig
    this.imgUrl = `${host}:${port}/public/${filename}`
}
```

esta es la funcion que uso para guardar las imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aca tengo el arbol de archivos, respetando las rutas

```
app.use('/public', express.static(`${__dirname}/storage/imgs`))
```

y luego aqui genero la ruta public donde se deberían leer los archivos.

este es el error que me muetra la consola en el front

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no logro encontrar porque esto funciona correctamente en local, pero a la hora de subirlo a mi servidor, esto no funciona.
espero puedan Ayudarme. Muchas gracias

Comment: Buen día, el código debe estar en texto con su respectivo formato y no en imágenes. Edita tu pregunta y haz las modificaciones que se te sugiere.

Comment: Puede deberse a diversos factores, tanto permisos como un problema de CORS, por favor suministra más información sobre tu aplicación de nodeJS si puedes indicarnos la configuración y que middlewares se encuentra utilizando y a su vez el error obtenido al momento de acceder a las imágenes. ¿Tus demás endpoints funcionan correctamente?

Comment: El resto de los endpoints funcionan correctamente, obtengo y escribo datos sin problema, el unico problema es al querer obtener imágenes

Comment: y si está cargando la imagen con la url que es? se me hace raro que la imagen que muestra error diga .svg.png